# Is it Possible to animate path.Data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have code something like this:

```
<Path x:Name="arrow" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Black"  Data="M34,115 C45,106 91,119 105,112 119,105 172,75.004352 188,82.003591" />
```

what I want is to animate the Data property of the path. I'm searching this from last two days didn't find a solution.
what I actually want is to show path bit by bit.

Does anyone have any Idea?

Comment: Update me if my answer helps

Comment: I could imagine an ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames with different values for the Data property.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"what I actually want is to show path bit by bit"

Do you mean something like this?

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="CWTrace">
            <!-- To run opposite direction, just swap the 'From' and 'To' values. -->
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset" 
                         Duration="0:0:5" From="100" To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CWTrace}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
    <Path x:Name="arrow" 
          StrokeDashOffset="0" StrokeDashArray="100"
          StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Black"  
          Data="M34,115 C45,106 91,119 105,112 119,105 172,75.004352 188,82.003591"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Obviously remove the RepeatBehavior for a one time anim, and tinker with values to get exactly what you're after. Cheers.

Comment: Yes...let me try then ill get back to you

Comment: Thanks it worked for every Data but you just have to adjust StrokeDashArray and From value....

Comment: @tabby I know. Glad you enjoyed tinkering. :)

Comment: How to keep the full path after animation ending (no repeat)?

Comment: @JokeHuang the last sentence in the example "Obviously remove the RepeatBehavior for a one time anim" tells you how, just remove `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` :)